# IE margin on link

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a problem with margin-top in IE.
I have given a link a margin-top of 2px to align it out correctly in Chrome. But this caused a offset in IE9.

Some code:

CSS

```
.show_cart{
    display: block!important;
    float:left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="show_cart">
    <a href="/reba/nl/winkelwagen">Toon Winkelwagen</a>
</div>
```

I hope there is a quickfix but I couldn't find it.

EDIT - Sorry I edit it here but I can't find the code thingy in the comment box. Anyway, I changed it to this based on the answer which stated that I should use the vertical align. Chrome is still displaying properly but in IE its now off by 2px to the TOP.

```
.vmCartModule .show_cart{
    display: inline!important;
    float:left;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.vmCartModule .show_cart a{
    vertical-align: baseline
}
```

Comment: So what you get is a div 2px too much to the right in IE?

Comment: nope its 2px too low in IE but just right in chrome.

Comment: Are you using HTML5 Boilerplate http://html5boilerplate.com/ ?

Comment: Have you tried it in Safari and Firefox? I know of the difference with FF that it accumulates (optelt) margin and padding to the width or height of div's, while other browsers don't. However it might be possible that Chrome does that now as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is more to it than just a margin. You should also consider font-size, vertical-align and more when you trying to line-up elements with texts. I would not recommend calculating pixels, it will never be consistent in all browsers and very hard to maintain. Instead, try to stick to "vertical-align: baseline", that is more deterministic. Using it you can be sure that your texts are always properly aligned.

Comment: .vmCartModule .show_cart{
    display: inline!important;
    float:left;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.vmCartModule .show_cart a{
    vertical-align: baseline
}

Comment: exact styles depend on the outer layout. which elements are you actually want to align? (why you all use float? it has very narrow application and should not be used for layout that could be achieved with other styles.)

Comment: I want to vertical align a div (with in there a img and some text) with a div (with in there a link) and I want that both texts are on the same height.

Comment: Then both of your div's may have "display: inline-block; vertical-align: baseline" (display:inline for ie7).

Comment: did that but it didnt work. In IE the link text is now 2px higher then the text in the other div.

Comment: Ok, starting super frustration mode here. The problem is solved when I remove the float. but then the div without the float is not correctly displayed anymore.

Comment: You should show a piece of your code if you want further help. Or check out this little example: http://jsfiddle.net/r2nbK/16/ - image with links with different font-sizes, but links are still on the same level.

Comment: You surely can achieve the layout you want without a "float"

Comment: True but how can I achieve the same layout? If I remove the float the div grows in height for some reason. Placing all the words underneath each other. I though I could fix this by adding some width to it but then I realised the div is changing texts all the time.

How can I give the div enough width for it to not grow in height and at the same time not cutting off words / leaving pointless whitespaces.

Comment: This is not related to this question anymore. And I can't help you without seeing your code and understanding which layout you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if you are using using HTML5 Boilerplate http://html5boilerplate.com/

You can use different value for the same class for IE9 -

```
.ie9 .show_cart{
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Or only if you wish to use jQuery for this, you can write -

```
if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) == 9){
  $('.show_cart').css({'margin-top':'0px'});
}
```

Comment: that's one way to fix it but I think it's cheating. I don't have enough experience to state thatbut to me it doesn't seem the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds exactly like IE's famous double margin bug, there is an easy fix as described [here](http://www.cssnewbie.com/double-margin-float-bug/).

Try changing `display: block;` to `display: inline;`. Or you can find another solution to it (there are plenty) or you can use the mentioned HTML5 boilerplate or something similar like [headjs](http://headjs.com/), etc.